# .on('mouseenter', function(){... not working

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have the following event:

```
$('.swiper-slide-active').on('mouseenter', function(){
            $(this).find('.overlay').addClass('show');
            $(this).find('.hotspot').addClass('show');
     })
```

Problem is that the class .swiper-slide-active is added when the slider is ready, but I thought with .on had replaced the .live event. Nothing happens when you rollover that element which has that class. Is there a way to wait until the class is added?

The slider is initiated like this:

```
 var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
            ....
          })
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a *delegated* `on` event for dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.swiper-slide-active', function(){
        $(this).find('.overlay').addClass('show');
        $(this).find('.hotspot').addClass('show');
 })
```

It works by listening for the event (in this case `mouseenter`) bubbled up to a non-changing parent (`document` is the default if you have nothing closer to the changing elements to hang it off), *then* it applies a jQuery filter, *then* it runs the supplied function against any matching elements *that caused the event*

If your case you would probably hang it from the `.swiper-container` for efficiency:

e.g.

```
$('.swiper-container').on('mouseenter', '.swiper-slide-active', function(){
        $(this).find('.overlay').addClass('show');
        $(this).find('.hotspot').addClass('show');
 })
```

*Note: Avoid using `"body"` to hang delegated events from, instead of `document`, as `body` has some style-related problems with delegated events.

Answer (score 1):

it would be something like this

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.swiper-slide-active', function(){
```

difference between `bind` and `live` with `on` is something like this

```
// Bind
$( ".swiper-slide-active" ).on( "click", function( e ) {} );
$( ".swiper-slide-active" ).bind( "click", function( e ) {} );

// Live
$( document ).on( "click", ".swiper-slide-active", function( e ) {} );
$( ".swiper-slide-active" ).live( "click", function( e ) {} );
```

Answer (score -1):

use `$( document ).ready( handler )`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.swiper-slide-active').on('mouseenter', function(){
            $(this).find('.overlay').addClass('show');
            $(this).find('.hotspot').addClass('show');
     })
});
```

Comment: The problem is the slider adds the class dynamically, not the ready event.

Comment: @This code will works same thing as this $(document).on('mouseenter',

Comment: Nope as `.swiper-slide-active` does not exist until the slider component completes (not the document). Please re-read the question: `"the class .swiper-slide-active is added when the slider is ready"`

Comment: ok ,actually we need this function if we want to use .on function on already present class or id..here situation is different.class is adding dynamically after slider is ready.

Comment: Correct. You need a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor.